# yad, how to create a simple question dialog?

Tags: scripting, dialog, zenity, yad

I know yad can do much more than zenity, but it also misses quickies like `--question`.
What is the simplest way to mimic that zenity option on yad?

Obs.: mimic quickies for other possibly missing options are much welcome!

*NOT REQUIRED:* As an opinion based answer bonus request, I would like to know if yad may resist the time, in a sense that zenity may last longer? I really want to implement scripts based on yad, but I would like to have an idea if it will still be maintained after 5 or 10 years? It seems that, ubuntu ppa at least, has auto-compile so packages may be auto-cooked fresh, is that also true? So basically, should I create something intermediary, where it will pop the dialog in yad or zenity (with severe functionalities limitations)?

Answer (score 3):

Does this help:

```
yad --image dialog-question --title Alert --button=gtk-yes:0 --button=gtk-no:1 --text "Is this a question dialog?"
```

This is the [source](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/45/idpl/17003956/numer/1/nazwa/yad) of my answer.

Apologies in advance for posting an answer that has not been tested.